# How can I draw a simple line, not connected to something?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How can I draw a simple line, not connected to something, in the web application draw.io?

Answer (score 3):

Open the "General" section on the left hand side

[image: The general library shown open in diagrams.net]

And drag and drop one the connector (towards the bottom of the library) into the main canvas

Comment: @rudd68 You should mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, and probably much has changed since in Draw.io, but I found myself struggling as well to create a simple vertical line, and bumped into this thread.

What I discovered is that a simple vertical or horizontal lines are available in the misc section from the left panel.

I find those better because you don't have to play with angles like you would with a simple line.

[image]

Comment: Wowww, I also need a vertical straigh line. Thanks a lot. You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

When you click to move the line, without releasing the button, press the `Alt` of the keyboard. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps described by @david.
[image]
And additionally, you can add that simple line as default from the context menu, after that when you will make new connections it will be done with the simple line.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I use a horizontal or vertical line. They are not connected to other objects,
and they can be rotated if you want to draw slanted lines.